# UNIX Command to recursively change permissions on directories?

Tags: unix

I just want to change permissions on directories, not the files contained within.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +`

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're in the directory you want to start in:

```
find . -type d | xargs chmod 755
```

or whatever permissions you want.

Answer (score 5):

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Comment: That will change files, not just directories.

Answer (score 2):

From where you want to change

```
find . -type d | xargs chmod a+x
```